# How can I use PHP to play video clips when the user clicks a thumbnail?

Tags: php, vlc

hi i'm wondering can php do this take this for example, if your not sure what im trying to explain :p

this is a example setup

/var/www/ this is where all the php etc files folders are
/var/www/sdata/ is where the videos are with same name as the output thumbs
/var/www/thumbs/ same name-example.jpg thumb

how can i use php to display video location, thumb location in php so when i click the thumb it plays in media player lets say vlc plugin ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. For the VLC part, you would need to push an .m3u file to the browser, which would probably not know to associate VLC with that file type unless you make it explicit within the browser's settings.